# Питон, построить пятиугольник

Tags: python, pillow

Задание такое: построить правильный пятиугольник со стороной a.

Тут обязательно должна использоваться библиотека Pillow.

Вот мой код:

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
a=int(input("Введите размер стороны а: "))

img = Image.new("RGB",(700,700), (2555,255,255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.polygon((0.6*a,1.4*a, 1.3*a,0.9*a, 2*a,1.4*a, 1.7*a,2.2*a ,0.9*a,2.2*a), fill="lightblue",outline =(255,0,0))

img.show()
```

Координаты подбирал сам, и в общем то, пятиугольник похож на правильный, но доказать это не просто. 
Также сделали замечание, что сторона "a" должна вводиться с клавиатуры в пикселях, а у меня получается своя условная единица.. Еще каким то образом нужно на картинке подписать "Это пятиугольник".

Вот результат работы моей программы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Рисовать вы уже умеете, значит остаётся чистая математика (точнее, геометрия) — посидеть с ручкой и бумажкой повыводить формулы расчёта координат, потом переписать их в код да и всё. Рисование текста является отдельным вопросом

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Зачем подбирать координаты, если их можно вычислить?

```
import math
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

x=250 #центр полигона (x)
y=250 #центр полигона (y)
n=5   #число сторон полигона
r=200  #радиус окружности в которую вписываем полигон
#получаем координаты вершин
coords=[(x + r * math.cos(2 * math.pi * i / n), y + r * math.sin(2 * math.pi * i / n)) for i in range(1, n+1)]

img = Image.new("RGB",(500,500), (255,255,255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

draw.polygon((coords), fill="lightblue",outline =(255,0,0))
unicode_font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 22)
draw.text ((100,40), u'Это многоугольник', font=unicode_font, fill='red' )
img.show()
```

[image: pentagon]

Ну, и поскольку изначально дается длина стороны, то радиус описываемой окружности тоже легко вычислить:

```
r = side/(2*math.sin(math.pi/n)) #side - длина стороны, n - количество сторон
```

Comment: а как привязать координаты текста к пятиугольнику, чтобы они зависили от размера пятиугольника, чтобы надпись была всегда рядом?

Comment: @ПётрКуртов у вас есть список координат вершин пятиугольника. Можете воспользоваться им. В функции `draw.text` вместо `(100, 40)` укажите координаты вершины (например `coords[0]`). Или центра `(x,y)`. Причем, можно использовать смещение `(x+10, y+55)`.